# Removing invisible old versions of self-made applications on MacOS

Tags: xcode, macos, file-association

**Problem**:
When I ctrl-click on a document (linked to an application I develop using Xcode), to open this document, the menu displays several versions of my application. Using Spotlight or the "System Information" application search, doesn't find the old versions.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:
This/these old versions are present on the computer if you archived them in Xcode's Organizer. As archives don't have the traditional myprogram.app name, the system cannot find them. To remove old versions, go to Xcode's organiser and remove the unwanted archives.

**Tip**: To find this out, I launched the unwanted version (ctrl-click on an application document) and launched to the Activity Monitor utility to get the_pid of the app. Then, in a Terminal, I entered:

`lsof -p the_pid | awk '$4 == "txt" { print $9 }`

and got the directory of the running application.

Comment: Tip: Use the Dock menu to get the directory of a runnning app.

Comment: I didn't worked, that's why I had to find out another way…